# How do I configure jshint to not give me the error "Bad line breaking before"?

Tags: javascript, jshint

It's giving me the error "Bad line breaking before ','" because I have code like the following

```
var one = 1
  , two = 2
  , three = 3
  ;
```

If I put the `,` at the end of the line instead of the beginning of the next, it doesn't complain. But I want to code this way. Is there a way I can make it not show this warning?

I looked though [JSHint's options](http://www.jshint.com/options/) but there isn't anything pertaining to this error.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the `laxbreak` answer, **`laxcomma`** option should actually be used for this particular situation (it has been implemented in the meantime). See http://jshint.com/docs/options/ for details.

Answer (score 14):

`laxbreak = true` is the option to set.

You can find the option on the main page of JSHint site as ["About unsafe line breaks"](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#laxbreak).

Comment: Thank you, that did it! I didn't think this option was for that when I saw it because it says "unsafe line breaks". I don't see how the line breaks in my code above are unsafe. I assumed it was talking about line breaks after a return/break/continue.

Comment: @DeaDEnD: That option is not checking if the code will really result in a problem or have no special handling for `var` (AFAIK). It is checking line endings on each line - it covers `return` statements but also this.

Comment: (JSHint maintainer here) By the way, we are working on separating laxbreak option with this comma-first notation.

Comment: @AntonKovalyov I noticed the upcoming `laxcomma` option, but I thought that `laxcomma` is only a subset of `laxbreak` so we can set `laxbreak = true` and `laxcomma = false` but not vice versa. So we cannot setup JSHint to have no problem with this `var` statement but report other unsafe line breaks. Am I wrong?

Comment: We still haven't made the decision about how laxcomma should work—it is tricky so if you have any thoughts or suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate them.