# Vim jshint error "bad line breaking before ','"

Tags: javascript, vim, jshint

I use jshint.vim and in the code like below I get an error "bad line breaking before ','"

```
var a = 5
  , b = 10;
```

How can I fix this? I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549394/how-do-i-configure-jshint-to-not-give-me-the-error-bad-line-breaking-before), but I'm not sure how can I use it to fix the problem in Vim. Is there any config file (except .vimrc) where I can set `laxbreak` or `laxcomma`?

Comment: Which jshint.vim file are you using?  Does it come with documentation?

Comment: I. Must. Resist. The. Urge. To. Downvote. Because. Of. That. Bloody. Leading. Comma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. I often use a leading comma style, and set the following preferences inside `~/.jshintrc`:

```
{  
//...other prefs
laxcomma  : true,
laxbreak  : true,
//... other prefs
}
```

If you don't already have a .jshintrc, those two settings enclosed in braces *a la* JSON will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about global configurations for the vim implementation, you'd have to consult the docs for that implementation, but you can put

```
/*jshint laxcomma:true */
```

at the top of your source files to set this on a per-file basis

#### Update

Looks like for the vim implementation you can set the config file using a global variable:

https://github.com/walm/jshint.vim/pull/3

You can then just create a json file and set `laxcomma:true` in it.